# Test if file under version control in pysvn (python subversion)

Tags: python, svn, pysvn

In [pysvn](http://pysvn.tigris.org/docs/pysvn_prog_ref.html), how do I test if a file is under version control?

Comment: There are two cases here. The file is not in any working copy, or the file is in a working copy but not added.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `client.status()` and check the `text_status` attribute of the returned status object. Example:

```
>>> import pysvn
>>> c = pysvn.Client()
>>> out = c.status("versioned.cpp")[0]  # .status() returns a list
>>> out.text_status
<wc_status_kind.normal>
```

That shows the file is versioned and unmodified.

```
>>> c.status("added.cpp")[0].text_status  # added file
<wc_status_kind.added>
>>> c.status("unversioned.cpp")[0].text_status  # unversioned file
<wc_status_kind.unversioned>
```

You can explore other possible statuses using `dir (pysvn.wc_status_kind)`

You can therefore wrap that up in something like:

```
def under_version_control(filename):
    "returns true if file is unversioned"
    c = pysvn.Client()
    s = c.status(filename)[0].text_status
    return s not in (
        pysvn.wc_status_kind.added, 
        pysvn.wc_status_kind.unversioned,
        pysvn.wc_status_kind.ignored)
```

---

If you wish to also address files outside an svn working directory, you'll need to catch and handle `ClientError`. E.g.

```
def under_version_control(filename):
    "returns true if file is unversioned"
    c = pysvn.Client()
    try:
        s = c.status(filename)[0].text_status
    catch pysvn.ClientError:
        return False
    else:
        return s not in (
            pysvn.wc_status_kind.added, 
            pysvn.wc_status_kind.unversioned,
            pysvn.wc_status_kind.ignored)
```

Comment: `File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module> pysvn._pysvn_2_7.ClientError: '...' is not a working copy`

Comment: @MattHickford As with the standard svn command, it is meant to be used on files that are within a working copy. If you want to also handle files outside working copies, place the `.status` call within a `try/except` block. Will update with example.